# Delete unwanted chars in a String Java

Tags: java, regex, string, stringbuilder

I'm trying to write a simple program that takes in a `String` as input. If the `String` matches a `regex` expression then it is returned. If not, I need to go through it, find each char that is causing the problem and remove it.

The problem I'm running into is I'm using a `for loop` based on the `String`'s length, but every time a `char` is removed, the length changes, therefore shortening the for loop. Eventually leading to an index out of range error when the for loop is half way done.

**Input**
"09fdghdghh0"  - (should return '090')

```
public String cleanID(String id){
        System.out.println("id = " + id);
        //String strRegex = "[a-zA-Z]+";
        String numRegex = "[0-9]+";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(id);

        System.out.println(sb.toString());

        if(id.matches(numRegex)){
            return sb.toString();
        }else{
            for(int i = 0; i < id.length(); i++){
                System.out.println("sb length = " + sb.length());
                if(!Character.toString(sb.charAt(i)).matches(numRegex)){
                    System.out.println(sb.charAt(i));
                    sb.deleteCharAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
return sb.toString();
```

**Output**

```
sb length = 11
sb length = 11
sb length = 11
f
sb length = 10
g
sb length = 9
d
sb length = 8
h
sb length = 7
sb length = 7
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7
```

As you can see the loop fails half way through. Is there a better way of doing this besides a for loop? Or am I just missing something obvious?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Show us what you want to replace. Maybe `replace()` or `replaceAll()` might help you.

Comment: As you delete characters, `sb` gets shorter, but `id.length()` doesn't get smaller, so eventually you'll access out of index. But there should be a better way to do this in the first place, so I don't want to make this an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex like  this will help :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "09fdghdghh0";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\D", "")); // \\D removes everything which is not a number
}
```

O/P

```
090
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to use the Pattern and Matcher classes

```
//Regex goes here
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
//Your string goes here
Matcher m = p.matcher(id);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));

}
```

This should extract whatever text you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `replaceAll` with a negative regex, and then compare to the original.

For instance:

```
String text = "10";
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("[^0-9]", " ").equals(text));
```

Comment: may not want to replace with a blank, perhaps "" instead.

Comment: @ErstwhileIII the replacement in my answer is rather arbitrary. The whole idea is to test validation, i.e. whether the original `String` equals the replaced `String`. If no replacement took place (i.e. no unwanted character), then they are equal and it returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

another approach is to loop over the whole string and then add the correct values (rather than removing wrong ones) to a resultString